# Good way to isolate tests that depend on an initializer

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I've really tried to start isolating my unit tests so I can pinpoint where errors occur rather than having my entire screen turn red with failures when one thing goes wrong.  It's been working in all instances except when something in an initializer fails.

Check out these tests:

```
@setup_directory(test_path)
def test_filename(self):
  flexmock(lib.utility.time).should_receive('timestamp_with_random').and_return(1234)

  f = SomeFiles(self.test_path)
  assert f.path == os.path.join(self.test_path, '1234.db')

@setup_directory(test_path)
def test_filename_with_suffix(self):
  flexmock(lib.utility.time).should_receive('timestamp_with_random').and_return(1234)

  f = SomeFiles(self.test_path, suffix='.txt')
  assert f.path == os.path.join(self.test_path, '1234.txt')
```

I'm mocking dependent methods so that the thing I'm testing is completely isolated.  What you notice is that the class needs to be instantiated for every single test. **If an error is introduced in the initializer, every single test fails.**

This is the offending constructor that calls the class's initializer:

```
SomeFiles(*args)
```

**Is there a way to isolate or mock the initializer or object constructor?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what testing packages you're using, but in general, you can usually just mock the `__init__()` call on the class before actually attempting to use it.  Something like

```
def my_init_mock_fn(*args, **kwargs):
    print 'mock_init'

SomeFiles.__init__ = my_init_mock_fn
SomeFiles()
```

This isn't probably exactly what you want as from this point on `SomeFiles.__init__` fn will always be the mock fn, but there are utilities like [voidspace mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) that provide a patch function that allow you to patch the class just for a specific scope.

```
from mock import patch
with patch.object(SomeFiles, '__init__', my_init_mock_fn):
    SomeFiles()
    ..other various tests...
SomeFiles() #__init__ is reset to original __init__ fn
```

I'm sure there's probably similar functionality in whatever mocking package you are using.

Just realized you're using flexmock, there's a page for `replace_with` [here.](http://has207.github.io/flexmock/user-guide.html#replacing-methods)

Comment: Mock \_\_init__.  Seems like a straightforward answer when I think about it now :) I used flexmock to do this flexmock(SomeFiles).should_receive('\_\_init__')

Answer (score 0):

What's causing the initialising function to fail? Maybe that's a bug that you should be looking into.

Another thing you can do, instead of mocking the object constructor, is simply mocking its return values. ie: Given this input, I expect this output -- so I'm going to use this expected output whether or not it returned correctly.

You can also stop testing on first failure. ([failfast](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult.failfast))

You also might want to reconsider how your tests are set up. If you have to recreate two files for every test, maybe ask yourself why. Could your tests be structured that you set up the two files, then run a series of tests, rinse and repeat. This would make it so only the series of tests assigned to that path fail, helping you isolate why it failed at all.

Comment: No, I'm not asking about a specific bug with a constructor.  I'm asking how to isolate the \_\_init\_\_ method in a test suite.

The two example tests aren't testing the initializer but they will fail if there is a bug in the initializer.  I want to be able to write a test that basically mocks the initializer so I can isolate a test for it.